# Spring 3 MVC - Url mapping not found (404) in production

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, spring-mvc

My app works fine on local tomcat 7 but on the prod tomcat 7 only index url ("/") and resources urls works, other urls are not found, "/login" for example.

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- FreeMarker Config -->
<beans:bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- FreeMarker View Resolver -->
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y" />

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Trying to resolve I changed the servlet-mapping from `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and I got no success, but it started to find the urls if I put the suffix ".jsp", eg: /login.jsp.

Can anyone help me understand why the tomcat is waiting this ".jsp" suffix? I'm not even using jsp in my app :s

Controller sample:

```
@Controller
public class Application extends BaseController {

    //...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        //..
        return "application/index";
    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        //..
        return "application/login";
    }

    //...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your application behaves differently, that's certainly because tomcat (or anything else) is not configured the same way in production. But it's hard to tell you more: if your application works on your local tomcat, then your configuration is probably fine.

Comment: I have found that if I put the suffix ".do" in the url the mapping is found. What bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might have apache sitting in front of tomcat in your production environment, and it is only passing through certain url's, eg: *.jsp
Alternatively, it could be a firewall blocking certain URL's.